# Installing material-ui in CRA project creates incomplete node_modules entry

Tags: material-ui

I have a problem trying to add Material-UI to my existing CRA project.

I run:

```
yarn add material-ui@next
```

I run:

```
yarn start
```

I get:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/FlatButton' in 'C:\Users\...\src\components\DialogModal'
```

Looking in node_modules under material-ui, many folders (including FlatButton) have no content. What went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation worked fine. The problem is that material-ui v1 has many breaking API changes from material-ui v0. One of these is the removal of the `FlatButton` component in favor of a `Button` with props. Many other components have also been changed, renamed, or removed entirely.

When you installed `material-ui@next`, you installed v1 instead of v0, because the `@next` flag points to v1. So, the absence of these folders and components is expected. You can take a look at which components should be available in [the v1 docs](https://material-ui-next.com/).

You have a couple of options:

1. Uninstall v1 and install v0 instead. You can install v0 by installing `material-ui` (without flags).
2. Migrate your code over to v1. You're going to have to do this eventually anyways, and v1 has many improvements over v0, so if this is a possibility for you I would recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've moved away from Material-ui for my project.

Comment: Ah well that's too bad, I've had solid luck using material-ui. Best of luck with whatever replacement you picked.